# How to reference "this" within anonymous listeners when using short notation?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, is there a way to reference the listener instance when using this short notation for anonymous classes? In this case `this` refers to outer context (e.g. the `Activity` instance) where `view` is defined:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    val self: View.OnClickListener = this // Not compiling, "this" references outer context
}
```

When using the longer notation where you explicitly state the interface to be implemented and where you explicitly override the callback method, the listener can be referenced through `this`:

```
view.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val self: View.OnClickListener = this // Ok
    }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term short notation for anonymous classes is not entirely correct. It's actually a short notation for anonymous functions, i.e. lambdas. Of course under the hood they are compiled to classes but from a programming language point of view, anonymous functions don't have identities and therefore it doesn't make sense to refer to their instances via `this`.

Comment: Seeing the "short notation" as lambdas explains why the anonymous class instance cannot be referenced. Unfortunately one is then forced to use the much "longer notation" just to reference that instance.

Answer (score 10):

You can get that resolved by adding an @ActivityName in front of 'this' reference
For example if your Activity name was MainActivity the solution would be:

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    val self: View.OnClickListener = this@MainActivity 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked but what is this kind of syntax's name?

Comment: That actually does not answer my question. I was looking for a way to reference the listener itself, which is just not possible as the accepted answer explains correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
 val animation = object : Animation() {
        override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation) {
            val layoutParam: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams? = playerView.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams?
            layoutParam?.topMargin = convertDpToPixel(position, this@SurahActivity).toInt()
            playerView.layoutParams = layoutParam
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't program in Kotlin, but there is no reference to `this` in your answer. How could it answer the OP? More over, when posting an answer, only a bit of code is not usually welcome. You shall give an explanation of what is this. I will remove my downvote if you fulfill this and I feel it seems a real answer.

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer by explaining how it works and answers the question.

Comment: 'this@SurahActivity' is the context. works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat related - here is an example of removing a listener from the listener itself that came about after not being able to refer to itself as reported by the accepted answer

```kotlin
    @Suppress("JoinDeclarationAndAssignment")
    fun View.foo() {
        // can't combine this with the assignment since it is referenced within the
        // body of the layout listener to remove itself
        lateinit var layoutListener: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

        layoutListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            // ... do something ...
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener)
        }

        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener)
    }
```

I don't typically see `lateinit` used in a local method field so this wasn't immediately obvious to me